# curl: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

```
C:\Users\casta>curl https://c5.ppy.sh
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

I've made my own CA, and I made a certificate from this CA.

The problem is, when I tried to access website with this certificate, It works fine!

but If I tried with curl or C# applications, It returns error.

C# error is here:

```
2019-02-28T09:20:33: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
2019-02-28T09:20:33: 위치: #=zGFbxUFU_LnBci6wJmmCy1$E=.#=z0YcFrd6MZP1A()
2019-02-28T09:20:33: 위치: #=zuFHGCPNOLQmjQEcRmqQHLnQ=.#=z3NGNjJ0=()
```

Comment: I got this issue while using PowerShell on a network with a self-signed certificate. Unsure how to tell PowerShell that the cert is fine, though.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I've been using curl through a mitm proxy for pen-testing and getting the same issue.

I finally figured that curl needs a parameter telling it not to check certificate revocation, so the command looks something like this:

```
curl "https://www.example.com" --ssl-no-revoke -x 127.0.0.1:8081
```

The `-x` parameter passes the proxy details - you may not need this.

Comment: Terrible solution though, because anyone can MITM you so theres very little point in using https.

Answer (score 12):

Don't panic... Please check your anti virus and turn off. It happened because your connection is blocked.

Comment: This is different with blocked. Your antivirus may do MITM virus check and that's why.

Comment: avg was blocking openai. It worked for me

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `--ssl` flag and omit the **https** like this

```
curl --ssl c5.ppy.sh
```

Comment: How does `--ssl` flag helps here? Just curious.

Comment: It tries with ssl and if fails revert to non-secure [docs](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl). If you specify https you force curl to use ONLY the SSL.

Answer (score 3):

just add -k to it , see here: curl -k https://release.solana.com/v1.10.8/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe — output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe — create-dirs

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the problem was in my AVG AntiVirus. When I disabled it ( specifically Web Shield ) then the issue had gone.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can ignore SSL errors using this code;

```
ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Sometimes useful if the site you are connecting to forgets to renew their SSL certificate, but you still want to download the content.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a CRL list, and publish it to webserver.