# How create Issues with API/CURL to Bitbucket

Tags: json, api, curl, bitbucket, issue-tracking

I'm trying to create issues in Bitbucket with the Windows CURL command, but it doesn't work, I'm getting this error message:

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "No import job started"}}
```

My command CURL:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/name/name2/issues/import -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @data.jsonson
```

I'm trying to send the following result in JSON:

```
{
"title": "title"
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can create issues?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should use a different URL path for posting issues, please see [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/issues#post) for post method. It should be like this: `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/reponame/issues`
For posting just an issue with a title you could use this:

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -u username@password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"title\" : \"test2\"}" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/reponame/issues
```

To post a content of the issue use content tag:

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -u username@password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"title\" : \"test2\",\"content\": {\"raw\": \"just test text\", \"markup\": \"plaintext\"}}"  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/reponame/issues
```

For example for me this worked (it's my private repo):

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -u myaccountname@mypasswordname -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"title\" : \"test2\",\"content\": {\"raw\": \"just test texts\", \"markup\": \"plaintext\"}}" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/dvmochalov/testrepo/issues
```

**--ssl-no-revoke**  - works only for windows curl and it's just in case if you are running Windows with antivirus software or working [with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486639/5681468).