# AWS cognito, domain not returning access token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, access-token

I created a user pool in cognito and set up OAuth2 agent in Cognito. Now iam trying to return the access token using the curl command . Below is the command

```
curl -X POST --user clientid:secret "https://mypooldomain.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials" -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

## But below i am getting following error

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

i tried with different ways from google that all point to the  issue with the curl command. But nothing working fine in this case.
How to resolve this kind of issue
Appreciate if anybody can help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: You could check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938026/curl-unknown-error-0x80092012-the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-r, maybe --ssl-no-revoke would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get tokens with oauth2.0 endpoints. Details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html