# Getting Curl error while token supplied as invalid in mapped port

Tags: docker, curl

My .yml file code

Quert-authentication:

```
image: datadog/squid

networks:
  - prod-tese-network
container_name: Quert-authentication

volumes:
  - ./conf/squid/authenticated:/etc/squid

ports:
  - 12000:3128
```

I am making this container using command :

```
"docker-compose -f filename.yml up  --build -d"
```

Now as per my understanding port `12000` in my local host is mapped to 3128 port of docker.

But when i run curl command from my local host :

```
"curl -k ftps://localhost:12000"
```

I get the following error :

> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid

Can anyone explain what is the reason of getting such error?
I have mapped many ports previously but never got such an error.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does adding --ssl-no-revoke to the curl statement resolve it? (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486639/3080207)
I think the ports are configured as you expect, otherwise I'd expect a timeout or for it just not to work
Adding as a comment because I'm just guessing

Comment: No that doesn't resolve it well my part of the code is working it doesn't involve CURL now anyways thanks for the reply...@mikey