# How to solve 'could not find package integration_test in the Flutter SDK' error

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, flutter-packages

I have an app, it is very simple and I keep getting this error:

> pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1
> second... Because bascis depends on integration_test any from sdk
> which doesn't exist (could not find package integration_test in the
> Flutter SDK), version solving failed.

I have tried

Pup upgrade, Pub get.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same error after changing my channel from master to stable. I was able to fix it by removing (or commenting out) the following library from pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
#  integration_test:
#    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: This also helped me when I was installing Flutter (default is stable, I did not know) on Mac OS and building my project there, while previously using Flutter (beta) on Windows

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this when I was trying to setup a flutter web project without enabling flutter web on my PC. I enabled [flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) and everything was okay.

Answer (score 2):

For me had to comment out `sdk` part like so:

```
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
   # sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely due to your network problem. Because the output says `(server unavailable)`.

Ways to debug this:

1. Try `curl https://google.com` to see whether your command line can connect to network.
2. Also try, for example, `curl https://flutter.dev` (or, try to curl the actual url your `pub get` is trying to access.

This may due to, for example, your network is broken. Or because you have a broken VPN, broken proxy, etc.

Comment: I got this log after running curl  next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Comment: curl "https://www.example.com" --ssl-no-revoke -x 127.0.0.1:8081 From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938026/curl-unknown-error-0x80092012-the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-r  and got  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081: Connection refused

Comment: @MohamedAbdelraZek Then sounds like your network has problem. It is not a Flutter problem :)