# I am getting an error when i run a command to install pip

Tags: python

I was trying to install pip to run a game. I followed a a couple of guides and the closest guide that gave me progress asked me to type:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

I typed it but nothing worked.

I was expecting pip to be installed but I got [this error message instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae3mP.png).

Comment: Welcome SO @random_coder :) Can you check if there's something in your antivirus log? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201885/1699311 Also check your proxy, especially if you are using self-signed certificate https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486639/1699311

Comment: You should include the error message as text instead of an image. Text is much more readable. Use [formatting help](/help/formatting) if you need it

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors