# How do I do a curl YELP REST Call?

Tags: rest, curl, command-line, yelp

Got a API_KEY from YELP Rest API, tried to use their curl example and pasted it to command prompt with my key. Didn't work for me,  What is the issue?

```
curl --request GET \
     --url 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=New%20York%2C%20NY&term=food&sort_by=best_match&limit=20' \
     --header 'Authorization: ******' \
     --header 'accept: application/json'
```

Looked up info online, found stuff about adding a BEARER and SSL Issues
[curl: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938026/curl-unknown-error-0x80092012-the-revocation-function-was-unable-to-check-r) but didn't know how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing it like this and it worked out!

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer *********" "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=New%20York%2C%20NY&term=food&sort_by=best_match&limit=20"
```

Note, maybe it was the "" or not using the short form.If someone could rewrite the above Rest call using the --ssl-no-revoke and Bearer option, that would be great.